# Nuxt3 / Vue3 - How to dynamically change rendered component, when the property changes?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have following code in my Nuxt3 application:

```
<template>
    <div v-if="conversationId">
        <h1>Current conversation: {{ conversationId }}</h1>
        <ChatWindow :conversationId="conversationId"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>

    const conversationId = useState('conversationId');
    
    const showConversation = (convId) => {
        conversationId.value = convId;
    }
    
</script>
```

When **showConversation('some-other-id')** function is called then **conversationId** changes correctly but **ChatWindow** component stays the same.

I want ChatWindow component to be replaced with new one with correct conversationId prop.
How to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

If you want your component to get updated on a variable change, you should use the `key` attribute. The component should get re-rendered as the key value changes.

Try it like `<ChatWindow :conversationId="conversationId" :key="conversationId" />`.

---

First answer about reactivity:

When you want the components to automatically update, you should use refs or computed properties.

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html#basic-example

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html

I don't exactly know, how it is working alongside useState(), but you could try to just put a ref around:

`const conversationId = ref(useState('conversationId'));`

or maybe use a computed property for the displaying part:

`const convId = computed(() => { return useState('conversationId') })`
and then use the convId in the html part.

Might be a test, if it's working with useState.

Comment: Reactivity is not an issue - useState is reactive itself. Value inside <h1> tag updates correctly. Component itself - not. But I got it finally working, see my answer.

Comment: Ah okay... Have you tried setting a new key to the component like `<ChatWindow :conversationId="conversationId" :key="conversationId" />`? As far as I know vue should update the whole component as the key changes. https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/

Comment: Yes! That works! So we have two correct answers but yours is pure :) Thank you! Can you write new answer with :key solution so I can accept it?

Comment: Glad to hear it helped! I updated my answer, hope its fine that way :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found this hacky solution to make it finally working:

```
const showConversation = async (convId) => {
    conversationId.value = false;
    await nextTick();
    conversationId.value = convId;
}
```

Wonder however, if there is more "native" way available.
I'll mark it as an correct answer temporarly.